# Label text is overlapping in text area box

Tags: javascript, html, css

Label text is overlapping in textarea box. In image you can see the issue text is overlapping with textarea box. It is possible to add a spaces between label text and textarea text

```css
.group {
    position: relative;
    margin: 7.5px 0;
}

.group textarea {
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.group label {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 10px;
    transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.smalltextinput {
    top: 5px !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: #d0d0d0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
<textarea oninput="this.style.height = &quot;&quot;;this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + &quot;px&quot;" id="information" name="information" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10">dddd</textarea>
<span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
<label class="smalltextinput"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Here the pedagogical reflection must be formulated. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">It may help to ask the following questions: 1. Why did x react like this, 2. What happened prior to the observed action and 3. How does x need to be met</font></font></label>
</div>

<div class="group">
<textarea oninput="this.style.height = &quot;&quot;;this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + &quot;px&quot;" id="information3" name="information3" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" spellcheck="false" style="height: 179px;"></textarea>
<span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
<label class="no-input smalltextinput"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Here the action must be formulated. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">So how did you choose to trade and with what effect.</font></font></label>
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM0Ur.png)

Comment: Increase padding-top of textarea. textarea content is overlapping with label content. Increasing top padding to 30/35 px will solve the issue

Comment: Can we add a fixed padding-top? because this group div is in for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be increasing padding-top for the text area.

```css
.group {
    position: relative;
    margin: 7.5px 0;
}

.group textarea {
    background: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 25px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.group label {
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 10px;
    transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.smalltextinput {
    top: 5px !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: #d0d0d0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
                    <textarea oninput="this.style.height = &quot;&quot;;this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + &quot;px&quot;" id="information" name="information" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10">dddd</textarea>
                    <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                    <label class="smalltextinput"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Here the pedagogical reflection must be formulated. </font><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">It may help to ask the following questions: 1. Why did x react like this, 2. What happened prior to the observed action and 3. How does x need to be met</font></font></label>

                </div>
```